# react-native init does not create ios folder using last version 69.5

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm new at react-native and I can easily create a react-native app using Expo, but there is no way using react-native init with Mac OS.

I have checked all the recommendations on internet, but the ios folder is never created.

Versions I have:
-Node v18.8.0

-Watchman v2022.08.22.00

-cocoapods v1.11.3

-xcode Version 13.4.1

I have tried all the recommendations I found: react-native upgrade, react-native-eject, reinstalling react-native-cli...,but no way.

I think that the template is not correct.

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Expo updated today, just download the latest version of react-native. After creating the project, type in your terminal `yarn add react-native@latest` / `npm install react-native@latest`

Comment: Thanks a lot Josué. This solves the issue. Now react-native init downloads a full template. 

I could not understand how such a basic process like this has been failing at least during 2 days.

Comment: If @josue-mendonca's answer solved your issue, please accept this answer. It will help others searching for the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mistyped, but rather than reinstalling `react-native-cli` try uninstalling:

> npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

As suggested in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), globally installed `react-native-cli` can cause issues, and missing the iOS folder/incomplete init is indeed one of them.

Once global `react-native-cli` is installed re-run `react-native init`